# MVC Bootstrap not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I want this to look like the following but apparently have no true understanding of bootstrap.

```
address: 123 haha drive
city: atlanta state: georgia zip: 281330
```

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <label>Address</label>
        <span>@Model.Address</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>City</label>
            <span>@Model.City</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>State</label>
            <span>@Model.State</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Zip</label>
            <span>@Model.Zip</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `label` here is not appropriate. Use a `span`.

Then

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
    <span>Address:</span>
    <span>@Model.Address</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <span>City:</span>
    <span>@Model.City</span>

    <span>State:</span>
    <span>@Model.State</span>

    <span>Zip:</span>
    <span>@Model.Zip</span>
  </div>
</div>
```